# How do filter dates in r using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

Below is my dataset:

```
df_gather %>% 
  filter(Country.Region %in% c("Italy")) %>%
  arrange(desc(Date)) #%>% 
  # filter(Date %in% c(2020-12-12))

########### output #############

Country.Region Date   Cases_Count
<chr>          <date> <int>

Italy   2020-12-12  1825775     
Italy   2020-12-11  1805873     
Italy   2020-12-10  1787147     
Italy   2020-12-09  1770149     
Italy   2020-12-08  1757394     
Italy   2020-12-07  1742557     
Italy   2020-12-06  1728878     
Italy   2020-12-05  1709991     
Italy   2020-12-04  1688939     
Italy   2020-12-03  1664829
```

**Issue:** when I try to `filter` this using below code I get `0 rows` in return

```
df_gather %>% 
  filter(Country.Region %in% c("Italy")) %>%
  arrange(desc(Date)) %>%
  filter(Date %in% c(2020-12-12))

######## output #########
0 rows
```

Also tried with quotes on dates but even then I get same result

```
df_gather %>% 
  filter(Country.Region %in% c("Italy")) %>%
  arrange(desc(Date)) %>%
  filter(Date %in% c("2020-12-12"))

######## output #########
0 rows
```

This seems but not able to figure out. Is there a different method of handling dates even in filtering ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date should be quoted and it is better to compare across similar types i.e. convert to `Date` class with `as.Date`

```
library(dplyr)
df_gather %>% 
   filter(Country.Region %in% c("Italy")) %>%
   arrange(desc(Date)) %>%
   filter(Date %in% as.Date(c("2020-12-12")))
```

Comment: I have also tried that but still getting 0 rows, that's what surprised me as well

Comment: @ViSa can you try by wrapping with `as.Date`. updated code

Comment: thanks alot @akrun, as.Date() worked. Will accept the answer as soon as it let me.

Comment: @ViSa it is always good to convert to the same type, but the string should have worked.

Comment: yes I agree but even I am not sure why it didnt work with quotes and that's when I thought may be dates needs to be used without quotes